# Git annex test add file, sync

Tags: git, git-annex

I have created a git annex repo, added data. I then went to check it out in another location in the following way (my goal is to checkout origin, add a test file, push it back to origin).

> git clone ../test_repo/
>   cd test_repo/
>   git status
>   git annex init DEV 
>   touch test.txt
>   vi test.txt
>   git annex merge
>   git annex add test.txt
>   git commit -am "test"
>   git push origin master git-annex
>
> However I am getting the following error
>
> Counting objects: 3, done.
>   Delta compression using up to 48 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
>   Writing objects: 100% (3/3),
>   364 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done. Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
>   remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch:
>   refs/heads/master
>   remote: error: By default, updating the current
>   branch in a non-bare repository
>   remote: error: is denied, because it
>   will make the index and work tree inconsistent
>   remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match remote:
>   error: the work tree to HEAD. remote: error: remote: error: You can
>   set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to remote:
>   error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing
>   into remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not
>   recommended unless you remote: error: arranged to update its work tree
>   to match what you pushed in some remote: error: other way. remote:
>   error:
>   remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the
>   default behaviour, set remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch'
>   configuration variable to 'refuse'. To /test_repo/ ! [remote rejected]
>   master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
>   error: failed to push some refs to '/test_repo/'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not recognise some of the commands that you used to establish your second git annex repository, but I can tell you how I did the same, and had it working.

```sh
  git clone ../test_repo/
  cd test_repo/
  git annex init "My new annex copy"
  git annex sync
```

Since it already has the original repository as the remote `origin`, it should be able to sync the metadata.

From then on you can add files and sync them to the other repository, e.g.

```sh
vi test.txt
git annex add test.txt
git commit -m "test"
git annex sync --content
```

I like to do a commit after calling annex add and before calling annex sync, because annex sync does some automatic commits.